# Rosbuild does not work on groovy source install

Tags: rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm running into frustrations getting a rosbuild package to build correct.

My machine was setup following these instructions.

However, I added a new package and rosbuild gives me the following output:

> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> mavlink_ros [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< mavlink_ros [SKIP] No rule to make target None
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 24 packages with 0 failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
> [ rosmake ] /home/ubuntu/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130626-183602

If it's any help, here is the output I get from "rospack find mk"

> [rospack] Error: stack/package mk not found

Any insight as to what is going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66035/rosbuild-does-not-work-on-groovy-source-install/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-06-26**:
Don't you have to use catkin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbuild cannot work without a Makefile.  Please see the [tutorial for creating a package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)

You should also make sure that you have the ros-groovy-ros installed which will bring in mk and all the other required packages to be able to build.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on 2013-06-26**:
That was exactly my problem. It appears http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/perception does not include mk amongst other packages.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-26**:
That was an oversight in the perception variant.  I've added core ros as a dependency.  That URL now has core ros, including mk.